# How to decode json data in mysql or PL/SQL or Stored Procedure without any programming language?

Tags: mysql

I have saved JSON encoded data using PHP, but I want to that in a column from MySQL prompt.
Without interact with PHP or any other language.
You can use PL/MYSQL , Stored procedure.
How is it possible?
Please, if possible give me a suggestion here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common_schema framework (https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/).

You could then use it like:

```
SELECT common_schema.get_option(profile, 'name') as name FROM users
```

where profile column contains:

```
{"name":"John","surname":"Smith"}
```